# VBA Macro to transpose rows to columns based on a keyword

Tags: excel, xml, vba, transpose

I have data in column A with 65000 rows of data. I need to transpose every x rows of data to x columns after every row that contains the text "< Amt >" without the spaces. For example, data from A1:A9 must be transposed to B1:J1 because row A9 contains the keyword. Yet data from A10:A19 must be transposed to B2:K2 because the keyword appears at the tenth row. I appreciate if anyone can provide VBA code for this.

I'm not sure if it's relevant but each row does contain its own XML identifier. EG, A1 starts and ends with `<AccountName>`.

| ACT Org |
| --- |
| 16 Ot Rd |
| Winsted |
| CT |
| 06028 |
| NONE |
| 501(C)(3) |
| UNRESTRICTED |
| 2000 |
| ADV Institute |
| 1010 Railroad Ave |
| Ste 31 |
| Bellingham |
| WA |
| 98225 |
| NONE |
| 501(C)(3) |
| UNRESTRICTED |
| 1500 |

To this

| ACT Org | 16 Ot Rd | Winsted | CT | 6028 | NONE | 501(C)(3) | UNRESTRICTED | 2000 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADV Institute | 1010 Railroad Ave | Ste 31 | Bellingham | WA | 98225 | NONE | 501(C)(3) | UNRESTRICTED | 1500 |

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbMwo.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpHsj.png)

```
Sub TransposeData()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowData As Variant
    
    'Set the number of rows to transpose to X
    Dim X As Integer
    X = 8 'Change this number to the desired value
    
    'Find the last row of data in column A
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Loop through each row of data
    For i = 1 To lastRow Step X
        
        'Check if the row contains the keyword
        If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, "<net>") > 0 Then
            
            'Transpose the rows above the keyword row into columns
            rowData = Range(Cells(i - X + 1, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)).Value
            For j = 1 To X
                For k = 1 To UBound(rowData, 2)
                    Cells(i - X, k + j - 1).Value = rowData(j, k)
                Next k
            Next j
            
        Else
        
            'Transpose the rows into columns starting from column B
            rowData = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + X - 1, 1)).Value
            For j = 1 To X
                For k = 1 To UBound(rowData, 2)
                    Cells(i - 1, k + j).Value = rowData(j, k)
                Next k
            Next j
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    'Delete the original data in column A
    Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    
End Sub
```

Comment: No offense, but I guess you should consider using a database system

Comment: Please share the screenshots of the before and the after. It is unclear what needs to be done since you're mentioning `A1:A9` (9 rows) and `A10:A20` (11 rows) yet in your code you're using a step (`X = 8`). Also, what has `<AccountName>` in `A1` to do with anything and especially with `<net>`?

Comment: Another contradiction in your question is "transpose every x rows of data to x columns AFTER every row that contains the text" but the next statement implies copying rows BEFORE the keyword: "A1:A9 must be transposed to B1:J1 because row A9 contains the keyword". Provide before and after as (with enough rows to make any patterns and differences clear). That might help you rephrase your question, because it might help you understand it better yourself. The good new is that transposing rows to columns is straightforward, once you've made clear what you need.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of data **as text which can be copy/pasted**,  *perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)* along with a screenshot of the desired results from that data. Ensure your data sample is representative of the patterns in your actual data.

Comment: I have edited my question to include example data, images, and to correct the written example of the Excel cell range.

Answer (score 0):

### Transpose Data in Place

**Main**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeDataInPlace()
    
    Const HEADER_COLUMNS As Long = 9
    Const DATA_COLUMNS As Long = 10
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = rg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim sData(): sData = rg.Value
    
    Dim drCount As Long
    drCount = Int((srCount - HEADER_COLUMNS) / DATA_COLUMNS) + 1
    If (srCount - HEADER_COLUMNS) Mod DATA_COLUMNS > 0 Then
        drCount = drCount + 1
    End If
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To DATA_COLUMNS)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    
    ' Headers
    For sr = 1 To HEADER_COLUMNS
        dData(1, sr) = ParseBetween(CStr(sData(sr, 1)))
    Next sr
    
    Dim c As Long: c = 1
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 2
    
    ' Data
    For sr = HEADER_COLUMNS + 1 To srCount
        dData(dr, c) = ParseBetween(CStr(sData(sr, 1)))
        If c = 10 Then
            c = 1
            dr = dr + 1
        Else
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next sr
    
    rg.Clear
    
    rg.Resize(drCount, DATA_COLUMNS).Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Data transposed in place.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**The Help**

```vb
Function ParseBetween( _
    ByVal GetString As String, _
    Optional ByVal FirstDelimiter As String = ">", _
    Optional ByVal SecondDelimiter As String = "<") _
As String
    
    Dim Pos As Long, Result As String
    
    If Len(GetString) > 0 Then
        Pos = InStr(GetString, FirstDelimiter)
        If Pos > 0 Then
            Result = Right(GetString, Len(GetString) - Pos - Len(FirstDelimiter) + 1)
            If Len(Result) > 0 Then
                Pos = InStr(Result, SecondDelimiter)
                If Pos > 0 Then
                    ParseBetween = Left(Result, Pos - 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
                
End Function
```

Comment: That partially worked. The only issue was that it cut off the 10th cell for the second row.

Comment: Sorry. Use `rg.Resize(drCount, DATA_COLUMNS).Value = dData`. Fixed it.

Comment: That did it for the test file. Thank you! 

When I run it on a longer dataset, it seems to jumble the rows. I'm thinking there may be other variations within the dataset and so it's creating errors because not all the data has 9 or 10 rows. I'm going to have to double down on the <Amt> to be sure that's the character to focus on as the signal to reset the process.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach using Power Query, available in Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365.

This is based on the fact that your data has each item surrounded by a pair of tags.

- Read in the table
- Split the tag from the value
- `Group` each set of data, using `<amt>` as the tag for the last item
- `Pivot` each set

With this you will wind up with a `Table` that has the information organized by `tag`

To use Power Query

- Assuming your data is in a contiguous range:
- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

*If this document were a valid XML document, there are other methods that could be used, but as presented, it is not*

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//Split type and value
    Split = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter({">","<"}),3),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Split,{"Column1.1"}),

//List of all column headers after pivoting
    ColHeaders = List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Column1.2]),

//Create "Grouping" Column
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Grouper", each if [Column1.2] = "Amt" then [Index] else null, Int64.Type),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Added Custom",{"Grouper"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Up",{"Index"}),

//Group by Grouper column
// Then Pivot each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Grouper"}, {
        {"Pivot", each Table.Pivot(_, ColHeaders,"Column1.2", "Column1.3")}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Grouper"}),

//Expand the pivoted subtables and set the data types
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Pivot", 
        {"BusinessNameLine1Txt", "AddressLine1Txt", "AddressLine2Txt", "CityNm", "StateAbbreviationCd", "ZIPCd", "RecipientRelationshipTxt", "RecipientFoundationStatusTxt", "GrantOrContributionPurposeTxt", "Amt"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Pivot",{{"BusinessNameLine1Txt", type text}, {"AddressLine1Txt", type text}, {"AddressLine2Txt", type text}, {"CityNm", type text}, {"StateAbbreviationCd", type text}, {"ZIPCd", type text}, {"RecipientRelationshipTxt", type text}, {"RecipientFoundationStatusTxt", type text}, {"GrantOrContributionPurposeTxt", type text}, {"Amt", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

***Your Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach. I am working from a full XML file. I’m currently copying and pasting the relevant lines out of the XML file but a holistic approach would be much better.

Comment: @ThomasJohnson power query can read in the XML file directly. Then you can parse it using a similar algorithm. If you run into trouble, post a more complete data sample that is a well formed XML.